# 'scatter3' needs vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
scatter3(X,Y,Z)
```

Error using scatter3 (line 64)
X, Y and Z must be vectors of the same length.

Matlab R2018b windows x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;

X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
Z = Z(:);

scatter3(X,Y,Z)
```

`scatter3` needs vectors, not matrices as far as I can see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html)

this is my result:
[image]

If you want to use `meshgrid` without reshaping the matrices you have to use `plot3` and the `'o'` symbol. So you can get a similar result with:

```
plot3(X,Y,Z,'o')
```

---

EDIT:

A question that arose in association with this post was, which of the following methods is more efficient in terms of computation speed: The function `reshape(X,[],1)`, suggested by me, or the simpler colon version X(:), suggested by @Argyll.

After timing the `reshape` function versus the `:` method, I have to admit that the latter is more efficient.

I added my results and the code I used to time both functions:

[image]

```matlab
sizes = linspace(100,10000,100);

time_reshape = [];
time_col = [];

for i=1:length(sizes)
    X = rand(sizes(i));             % Create random squared matrix

    r = @() ResFcn(X);              
    c = @() ColFcn(X);

    time_reshape = [time_reshape timeit(r)/1000]   % Take average of 1000 measurements
    time_col = [time_col timeit(c)/1000]       % Take average of 1000 measurements
end

figure()
hold on
grid on
plot(sizes(2:end), time_col(2:end))
plot(sizes(2:end), time_reshape(2:end))
legend("Colon","Reshape","Location","northwest")
title("Comparison: Reshape vs. Colon Method")
xlabel("Length of squared matrix")
ylabel("Average execution time [s]")
hold off

function res = ResFcn(X)
    for i = 1:1000    % Repeat 1000 times 
        res = reshape(X,[],1);
    end
end


function res = ColFcn(X)
    for i = 1:1000    % Repeat 1000 times 
        res = X(:);
    end
end
```

Comment: Why should I reshape X Y Z ?  X Y Z are vectors at first, because they are one row respectively.

Comment: As far as i can see X,Y and Z are 33x33 Matrices

Comment: As X Y Z are matrices, why mesh can plot them? I can not imagine how it plot.

Comment: @Y.zeng: `meshgrid` output are matrices. Please examine the output of a function by using a small and simple example. You should do this for **all** functions you encounter. If you want to plot with matrices, you need to use `plot3`, not `scatter3`. `scatter3` is just a specialized version of `plot3` anyway.

Comment: I added somthing to my answer, try: `plot3(X,Y,Z,'o')`

Comment: Instead of reshaping a simple colon call works: `scatter3(X(:),Y(:),Z(:))`

Answer (score 4):

As shown in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#btrui17-1-X), X, Y, Z must be vectors. (When you enter an article on mathworks from Googling, say, "[matlab scatter3](https://www.google.com/search?q=scatter3+matlab)", you will first see the syntax for the function. Blue text means hyperlink. All the inputs are linked to the bottom of the page where their exact typing is defined.)

The reason is (probably) as follows.

As stated in the documentation, `scatter3` puts circles (or other symbols of your choice if you modify the graphic object) on 3D coordinates of your choice. The coordinates are the *i*th element of X, Y, Z respectively. For example, the *x*-coordinate of the 10th point you wish to plot in 3D is `X(10)`.

Thus it is not natural to input matrices into `scatter3`. If you know X(i), Y(i), Z(i) are indeed the coordinates you want to plot for all *i*, even though your X, Y, Z are not vectors for some reason, you need to reshape X, Y, Z.

In order to reshape, you can simply do `scatter3(X(:), Y(:), Z(:))` which tells Matlab to read your arrays as a vectors. (You should look up in what order this is done. But it is in *the* intuitive way.) Or you can use [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html). Chances are: `reshape` is faster for large data set. But ofc `(:)` is more convenient.

Comment: But X Y Z are matrices, how mesh plot them. I know that mesh can do it.

Comment: I now know why scatter's meaning. I just can not imagine how mesh(X,Y,Z) works.

Comment: @Y.zeng: That will be a different question. Basically, it is a `plot3` with an interpolation method to do what the documentation shows.

Comment: Okay, let it be.

Comment: I haven’t timed these, but I’d be surprised if `reshape` we’re faster than `(:)`. The latter doesn’t need to validate input arguments after all.

Comment: @CrisLuengo just timed it out of pure curiosity. `reshape` seems to need on average 1.6 as long as the `:` version, doesnt matter how large the matrices.

Comment: @ga97dil Cool! Thanks for doing that! For both of them it’s an O(1) operation (no data copy), so size of matrix shouldn’t matter. Nice to see that verified too.

Comment: @ga97dil: feel free edit in your test results if you wish. I can add some more as needed.

Comment: @ga97dil: Awesome. From now on, my priority is given to `:`. Thank you. (I upvoted your answer earlier. Can't upvote again.)